# Why does Python char binding to C fails in c function?

Tags: python, c, binding, char, ctypes

I need to use in Python C-coded translation of string to reverse polish notation and calculation of it.
For this I do next:

```
import ctypes

input_string = bytes(memoryview("2 + 3.2 + 4".encode()))
result = str(self.model.functions['equal'](input_string))
```

where equal function is in:

```
    def init_functions(self):
        equal = self.c_lib.equal
        equal.restype = ctypes.c_double
        equal.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
        self.functions.update({'equal': equal})
```

Where function in C is:

```
double equal(char *input) {   
    stack S = parseInput(input);   
    stack polish = toReversePolishNotation(&S);   
    return calculate(&polish); 
}
```

It does calculation perfectly fine in C (checked with tests and memory leaks), always delivering the right answer.
But when I use this function in Python, it occasionally delivers some wrong output.
Sometimes it is 0, sometimes it is some strange number, sometimes it is endless cycle.
For example:
[C result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONtsp.png)
[Some random Python result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLy5Q.png)
[Strictly the next after random result in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwEW4.png)

More of it, my beloved example is "39.9 - 52.0". In C it is always as stated. But Python passes this string to C as "39.9 - 52.9".

I tried to set input_string = '' in Python, tried to memset char* input by '\0', tried to use different implementations of input_string:

```
input_string = ctypes.c_char_p("2 + 3.2 + 4".encode('utf-8'))
input_string = bytes("2 + 3.2 + 4", encoding='utf-8')
```

Python never delivers right answer consequently. It always fails. I don't know, if I need to free input_string somehow or something else is wrong.

Comment: Any reason why not using `input_string = b"2 + 3.2 + 4"`? Did you try *printf*ing the input string in *C*? Also: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): add a single snippet containing **all** (*Python*) code, instead of scattering it in many pieces (that put together it's not the whole thing).

Comment: Show the working C code and non-working Python code as a complete example as requested, but likely @EmanuelP is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The C code expects a pointer to mutable memory (probably for some tokenization). For that you need to use `create_string_buffer`.

```
input_string = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"2 + 3.2 + 4")
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) and [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that's the case. Technically it should work with a read only string (even *const* is missing from the *C* signature) as function doesn't need to modify it.

Comment: There is indeed no _const_ in the signature. It's quite likely it uses some string splitting that inserts null characters. Regardless, if there is no _const_ you should expect it to be mutable.

Comment: Nah.
String doesn't change, make it const without any other modifications to C code.
Didn't help, as did creating_buffer.
It spits out random results for no reason.

Comment: @Graien In that case, you should follow the first comment and create a [mre] because we cannot try it like this. You have not provided all code.